# Background Image Problems for my website using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am quite new to coding and made a website for a college presentation. I uploaded the website today to the internet and the background images that are in my files are not showing up on the website. I'm fully expecting a massive rookie error to be the source of my pain and problems with all this.
Any feedback would be much appreciated as I am confused and definitely out of my comfort zone.
Thanks, Sam.

[What my home page should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACrwv.jpg)
[What my home page looks like rn.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FezLy.png)

```css
.index-banner {
    
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>The Cloververse: A Transmedia Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--This is the main content -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    

<header>
 <a href="index.html" class="header-brand">Cloverfield: A Transmedia Project</a>
 <nav>
 <ul> 
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="About%20the%20Project.html">Project</a></li>
<li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
<li><a href="Resources.html">Resources</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>    
<main>
<section class="index-banner">
<div class="vertical-centre">
<div class="Index-html">
<h2>Cloverfield:<br>A transmedia Project</h2>  
<h1>This website is related to the Cloververse. The cinematic universe regarding the Cloverfield film franchise. This website is part of a project on Transmedia. This serves as a platfrom for all things related to the Cloverfield film franchise and its surrounding ARG. The website will have videos from and about the ARG, links to resourceful websites and a smaller more in depth piece on why I have made this website.</h1>  


<iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/bkbh97abxVMKQ" width="1000" height="400" style="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</section>  
    
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted relevant code like the CSS for the background image directly instead of a link

Comment: Are you getting any missing file errors in the Dev console?

Comment: I can't  see where you acutally sets the background-image. please provide CSS

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (as far as I can infer about what you're trying to accomplish) when I specify the background image for the index-banner css class:

```css
.index-banner { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-image: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3816463.jpg");
  }
```

everything behaves as expected. Don't forget to change the link in the url to where your missing image is stored. Note this won't add the background image behind your header/nav section, to include the header, the rules above should be adapted to the body tag of the page instead.

I hope I've understood this correctly